# Using an Arduino to control an ON / OFF connection between two pins

Tags: arduino, logic-control, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I've got this driver: http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1182

... a A4988 stepper motor driver carrier

[image]

I'm attempting to control a connection between the RESET and SLEEP pins with logic ( code ) running on my Arduino. The motor runs perfectly when these two pins are connected however I'd like to control when the stepper is powered off from my Arduino ( and thus not generating extra heat )

I'd like to:

1. designate a pin to control the connection between these two pins
2. use a "digitalWrite" to the above pin with a HIGH or LOW to
   switch power on and off from the stepper

NOTE: The [data sheet](http://www.pololu.com/file/0J450/a4988_DMOS_microstepping_driver_with_translator.pdf) mentioned that for the driver to be powering the stepper both RESET and SLEEP needed to be in switched on ( HIGH )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are going about this incorrectly.  The reason why pololu is telling you to connect the two pins is because the sleep pin has a pullup resistor on their breakout board.

Connecting reset to the sleep pin is equivalent to connecting the reset pin to high.

You can achieve your goal by connecting reset pin to high (5V through pullup resistor) and connect the sleep pin directly to your arduino just like the step/dir pins.

Comment: solid explanation and for looking into the docs you +1